# Time out retrieving items from list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem retrieving items from a fairly large list. I can quickly and easily retrieve items from a small list with more or less 50 items, but when I try to retrieve items from a list containing more or less 4600 items, the sqlsever.exe process spikes for the duration of the request, but the items are never retrieved. If have set up the web applications throttling settings, so it can’t be that which is causing the problem. Here is the code that I originally used to retrieve the items. There is really nothing special to it.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
 {
  SPList list = web.Lists[uid.ToString()];
  SPListItemCollection itemCollection = list.Items;

  foreach (SPListItem i in itemCollection) //This is where the code stops responding
  {
   //Use list items
  }
 }
}
```

After that didn’t work, I tried a couple of other methods to retrieve the items from the list. Here is the code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[uid.ToString()];  

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "";
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;

SPListItemCollection itemCollection = list.GetItems(query);

//The code stops here
//I added this part for interest sake, i wanted to if it was the looping that caused the problem
//It seems the when you try to access properties of the item collection that the problem occurs
int itemCount = itemCollection.Count;

foreach (SPListItem i in itemCollection) 
{
 //Use list items
}
```

I also tried:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[uid.ToString()];
SPListItemCollectionPosition pos;
DataTable dt = list.GetDataTable(new SPQuery(), SPListGetDataTableOptions.None, out pos); //The code stops responding here

foreach (DataRow i in dt.Rows)
{
 //Use data rows 
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a very long struggle we found a solution.

We found this post:

http://trycatch.be/blogs/tom/archive/2009/04/22/never-turn-off-quot-auto-create-amp-auto-update-statistics-quot.aspx

We tested it and it worked!!!

So all we had to do was switch "Auto create statistics" and "Auto update statistics" to true, and to problem was solved

Thanks for all the replys

Comment: link no more available

Answer (score 1):

You'll kill your server if you always try to retrieve all items either through `list.Items`, `list.GetItems(query)` (with an empty query).

You need to define a relevant query and specify the amount of results you want to retrieve through the RowLimit property of your SPQuery

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>"; // any relevant query here
query.RowLimit = 50;
```

Failing to do so will load all the items in memory prior to any other operation. You will probably kill your application pool available memory or your sql server memory when it will try to load all these data !

Hope that helped.

Comment: I understand the need to retrive only relevent rows of from a list to conserve resources, but in the in this specific instance we need to retrieve all the items in the list. We use this code in a caching framework we buitl a while back. What it does is loads all the items into cache so our web parts can retrieve the data quickly. This code works fine on our dev environments, we only have this problem on the clients staging environment. We have used this with many clients, and never had a problem, and other clients had lists with 10 000 items, and we had no problem retrieving the items.

Comment: This is why i think its a SQL problem, and not a SP or coding problem

Comment: Mmmmh interesting. Don't you think that there are some heavy items (maybe some with attachments, although I'm not sure that attachments are loaded when the SPListItem is loaded ? Did you check the memory allocation for the server ? Maybe there's a ram shortage ? If this is environment specific (staging, I hope it won't be the case in production) I would add a specific switch in my application that would load "by batch" and cache the result (eg : the first 2000 thousands, then 2000 till 4000, you get the point) but i'm still pretty sure it's a ram issue. Is this a dedicated database server ?

Comment: There aren't any attachments on any of the list items. I have checked the memory allocation of the system, its has 4GB of memory, and only 2.2GB is being used. And there is no limit to the amount of RAM SQL can use. Unfortunately the staging and production are sharing the same dedicated SQL server. SharePoint is running on a VM on another server The same as our dev environment. So they both have the same problem.

Comment: Ive been running some tests on the environment. I wrote a console app that query's the list that i try to cache. I only have problems querying one specific list. This is the largest list with the most columns and the most lookup fields. Only when i delete all of the lookup fields in that list, can i successfully query the list. Any ideas why the lookup fields could be breaking the site?

Comment: No, absolutely not, because as you know, the lookup are just ID;#value, that's nothing huge and even if you point to a calculated field this is still simple text for storage retrieval (the targeted item will not be retrieved). I was going to suggest you to query as well the targeted list but there is no added value. Did you run a checkdisk on the db server ? Some part of the database might be under some corrupted clusters ? Keep me informed, this is really strange. Nice weekend.

Comment: Hi there. I did a scan disk on the SQL Server, but there was nothing strange going on on the disk. I tried to retrieve the items from the list in batches using ListItemCollectionPosition, but that didnt help either, I'm busy writing an app that will re-populate the list. My idea is to completely delete the list and re-create it. Maybe that will help some how

Comment: Maybe the list schema is broken "for some reason", did you try to empty the list prior to the recreation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get data using [CAML](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) query.

Once you have data you can put that in [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the items not all at the same time. You can load them bulk wise (page wise) with the help of `SPQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx).